# Why can't I insert 10 digits when my column is INT(10)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this column that's
`INT(10) ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',`

But when I insert something like `9100000010`, I get `4294967295`

It should have allowed 10 digits there, right?

How to do this right?

Comment: I think your fundamental problem is that you are confusing numbers with representations of numbers. What do you think that "10" means?! What would it mean to limit a number to 10? 10 what? (If you're thinking digits, well, numbers don't have digits. How many digits does thirty have? Well, it depends what base you express it in. Representations of numbers have digits.) It makes no sense to limit a *number* to 10 digits. (Except as shorting to mean "a number that can be expressed in base 10 with 10 digits or fewer. But MySQL stores *numbers*, not expressions of numbers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Int has maximum value range :

```
INT 4   -2147483648 2147483647
        0   4294967295 (unsigned )
```

hence, you are getting  the maximum value due to the overflow.
use bigint instead, which has 8 bytes
and you shall be fine.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types

```
BIGINT  8   -9223372036854775808    9223372036854775807
          0                 18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 5):

Largest value possible in INT field in MySQL is `2147483647`, your value `9100000010` is greater than that. That is why it is overflowing to `4294967295` which is Max for Unsigned Integer.

[11.1.4.1. Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

```
INT    4    -2147483648 2147483647
```

Use `BIGINT` if you want to store larger number, which ranges from:

```
BIGINT  8   -9223372036854775808    9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, INT(10) does not mean that values are limited to 10-character values. It only means that MySQL will try to pad these values with spaces/zeroes when returning them.

The numeric range of any signed INT including INT(10), INT(5) or any other INT(n) is:
 -2,147,483,648 ... 2,147,483,647, which is 10 digits at most.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you get int max value. INT(10) is ment for number padding not for limiting number of characters.

MySQL will try to pad these values with spaces/zeroes when returning them.

Answer (score 0):

you reached the maximum for int. 
The int maximum value range for int in mysql is 4294967295 (unsigned). 
So you have to use BIGINT.  You can get more informations about this here: 
[Mysql Numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types)

Hope this helps

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

> It should have allowed 10 digits there, right?

**NO**, size of INT and integer types in mySQL is to set the **display** width when field has ZEROFILL specified.

for example if the value you inserted is 123456 then when you query it, it will displays as 0000123456 , it is just the display width and doesn't affect the value.

so the value range is determined by the datatype itself, not the display width. to store greater values, you should change the datatype to a suitable one, like [BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types).

from [mySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

`INT : A normal-size integer. The signed range is -2147483648 to 2147483647. The unsigned range is 0 to 4294967295.`

Comment: @Norman In other words, for your purposes, the number in parentheses is irrelevant. It could be 2 or 11 and would make no difference to the range of values accepted, only how they are displayed when ZEROFILL is used. Use BIGINT for numbers in your desired range, and don't bother with the bit in parentheses.