# wrong value stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store form value in database but wrong value is stored in database for `mobilenumber` field in my table. In table, I have the following 4 fields.

id (auto increment),

mobilenumber,

operator,

date.

Value displayed correctly when I do echo.

But while storing mobile number in database table, I am not getting the same value of mobilenumber field.

I have the following code.

**home page**

```
<?php include "header.php"?>
<body>
<div class="form-group">

    <form  name="myForm" action="invite.php"   method="post" class="elegant-aero" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" >
        <h1> Congratulations. You have been invited to win Rs 148 Recharge.
            <span>Please fill all the details to get a Rs 148 Recharge.</span>
        </h1>
        <label>
            <span>Mobile Number</span>
            <input name="Mobile" id="mob" type="text"  placeholder="Prepaid Mobile Number" required />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Operator</span><select name="Operator">
                <option value="Select Operator">Select Operator</option>
                <option value="Bsnl">BSNL</option>
                <option value="Airtel">Airtel</option>
                <option value="reliance">Reliance</option>
                <option value="Vodafone">Vodafone</option>
                <option value="Videocone">Videocone</option>
                <option value="Aircel">Aircel</option>
                <option value="Telenor">Telenor</option>
                <option value="Idea">Idea</option>
                <option value="Tataindicom">Tataindicom</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Proceed To Recharge" />
        </label>
    </form>
    <div>
</body>
<?php include "footer.php" ?>
</html>
```

page 2

```
<html>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "recharge_project";
/**$mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
$operator = $_POST['Operator'];
**/
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (id, mobilenumber, mobileoperator) VALUES ('', '$_POST[Mobile]', '$_POST[Operator]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "datainserteed";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
<?php include "header.php"?>
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<div class="form-group">

    <form  class="elegant-aero" >
        <p> Invite your 10 active <span style="color:#FF0000"> WhatsApp Friends</span> <!-- and 3 <span style="color:#FF0000">WhatsApp Groups </span>-->to claim your recharge
        </p>
        <label>

<a class="button1" href="whatsapp://send?text=http://rechargetoday.net || Super Promo offer. Get Rs 148 free recharge. Visit above link to get your recharge.NOTE :Offer valid across India!!" onclick="return myFunction()" >Invite</a>
       </br>
        </label>
  <?php echo"</br>";?>
        <label>
            <a name="finish" type="submit" class="button2" onclick="return aboveTen()">Finished- Inviting 10 friends </a>
        </label>
        <label>


        </label>
    </form>
    <div>


</body>

</html>
```

I have the following JS code.

```
var invite = 0; 
function ValidateForm()
{ 
    var fld= document.forms["myForm"]["Mobile"].value; 
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/; 
    if(fld.match(phoneno)) 
    { 
        return true;
    } 
    else
    { 
        alert("Please enter valid number"); 
        return false; 
    }
} 
 function myFunction(){ invite ++; }
```

When I echoed `$sql`, I got the below query.

```
INSERT INTO customer (mobilenumber, mobileoperator) VALUES ( 8574968578, 'Vodafone')
```

Comment: What is the data type for both Mobile and Operator?

Comment: how is the value wrong? Can you give an example of the value you type in the input, and the value that is inserted into the database? Could the value be changing due to the `onsubmit="return ValidateForm()"`

Comment: can you give example, the expected mobile number and what saved in db? and what do you do in `onsubmit="return ValidateForm()"`?

Comment: check the data type of mobile number and if it is int, remove quotes in insert query

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO customer (mobilenumber, mobileoperator) VALUES ( '8574968578', 'Vodafone')
Duplicata du champ '2147483647' pour la clef 'mobilenumber. i am giving input as 8574968578 . but its storing 2147483647.

Comment: Ok do one thing echo your query then put `die();` and run the file and what query is echoing in browser, copy that query and execute it in mysql and check what it returns and let me know.

Comment: var invite = 0;
function ValidateForm() {
    var fld= document.forms["myForm"]["Mobile"].value;
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
    if(fld.match(phoneno))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please enter valid number");
        return false;
    }
}

function myFunction(){

invite ++;

}

Comment: @mrdatt What is the datatype of "mobilenumber" in your database table?. Use "BIG INT" or "VARCHAR(20)" to insert phone number. Also refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393672/why-cant-i-insert-10-digits-when-my-column-is-int10)

Comment: @mrdatt update your question with this JS.

Comment: INSERT INTO customer (mobilenumber, mobileoperator) VALUES ( 8574968578, 'Vodafone')  . this is displayed in browser

Comment: @mrdatt do you have `2147483647` number already on your table?

Comment: Ok, execute that same query in DB and tell me what they return?

Comment: thank you brothers. now its working. there was problem in datatype.

Comment: It's on the first comment.

Comment: yeah , its my first time. will take care in future.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (id, mobilenumber, mobileoperator) VALUES ('', '$_POST['Mobile']', '$_POST['Operator']')";` rather 
`$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (id, mobilenumber, mobileoperator) VALUES ('', '$_POST[Mobile]', '$_POST[Operator]')";`.